# How to configure SoapUI mock service with non self signed certificate X509 for SSL

Tags: ssl, certificate, soapui

I have no problem to set up SoapUI mock service with self signed certificate by following the steps at

http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/securing-mockservices-with-ssl.html .

But now I want to test the mock service with a "real" certificate issue by Entrust Certification Authority - L1C.

Other information for this certificate is

- Ensures the identity of a remote computer
- 1.2.840.113533.7.75.2
- 2.23.140.1.2.2

It is valid until 2016.

I used the command to import the certificate to server.keystore .

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\keytool.exe -import -alias server -keystore server.keystore -storepass mypasss -file server_cer_issued_by_entrust.cer
```

(if I replace `server_cer_issued_by_entrust.cer` with a self signed (created) certificate it works)

I got the error in SoapUI which says ssh handshake error.

I just realize that it maybe not possible since the mock service is `127.0.0.1` but the actual certificate is issue for a web service like "mydomain.com", is that right?

Answer (score 0):

`SOAPUI` runs over `java`, and when `java` connects to `SSL` url performs two validations:

1. Validate that the server certificate is trusted.
2. Validate that the common name in subject distinguished name of the server certificate matches the domain.

I assume that the first validation pass since in the link instructions which you provide its specify the same keystore in mock service for both: keystore and truststore, and since server certificate is imported in this one there is no problem to pass this validation.

So probably as you said the problem is that your mock service is on `127.0.0.1` and your certificate is issued to be used in `mydomain.com`.

A possible workaround is to disable `SSL` validation however this has no sense since as you said in the question you want to test the service with "real" certificate, instead maybe you can try editing `host` file and adding the mapping for `127.0.0.1` ip address for your certificate server domain, in your case:

```
127.0.0.1       mydomain.com
```

And then change the SOAPUI endpoint for your mock service to `https://mydomain.com`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks. I did change the windows `hosts` file and using mydomain.com in soap. I still get the error.

Comment: Did you edit the host file and change the SOAPUI endpoint to connect to `https:// mydomain.com` and doesn't work?

Comment: yes. I did that and error from the SOAPUI log is `no cipher suites in common`

Comment: Is it the same error which you had before the changes in `host`? I'm not sure, however this error not seems directly related to the domain name validation. I'll look for more info about it.